# AppleScript for lifting & stamping latitude & longitude of photos onto themselves

Tags: geolocation, aperture

After repairing my Aperture library, I have over 3000 photos with latitude and longitude information whose place displays as "Unnamed location" on the map. If I lift and stamp the data using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, Aperture names the place automatically. However, I don't want to have to do this for all 3000 pictures manually.

I think it should be possible to automate the process using AppleScript. However, I'm not sufficiently experienced to piece it together myself and was unable to find any help googling. What I have so far is

```
tell application "Aperture"
    set imageSel to (get selection)
    if imageSel is {} then
        error "Please select an image."
    else
        repeat with i from 1 to count of imageSel
            [What goes here to lift and stamp latitude and
             longitude of each individual photo onto itself?]
        end repeat
    end if
end tell
```

Any help, links or tips would be much appreciated.